# Gradle and Specs2 : Specs2-HtmlOutput

Tags: scala, junit, gradle

Id like to generate HTML-Output as stated in: http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Runners.html via the JUnit-Runner

The documentation states that  ''you can use the -Dspecs2.commandline property and pass it the html or console values.''

How to do that in a gradle task.

Yes, I know that gradle can produce HTML-Test-Reports but I need the one specs2 can generate.

One problem still remains. I don#t get a navigation menu on the left. Each page has a seperate menu and the results

Answer (score 2):

Just use the systemProperty whitout the -D

```
test {
    systemProperty "specs2.commandline" , "html"
    systemProperty "specs2.outDir"  ,   "$buildDir/reports/specs2" // to put the reports in the same dir as other gradle reports
}
```